# What if I not implement the onBackPressed() method in Android?

Tags: android

What happens if I don't implement, i.e. don't override, the `onBackPressed()` in Android? In other words, what's the default behavior of Android when the user click the back button and `onBackPressed()` is not overridden?

I think that the `super.onBackPressed()` method is called by default but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you don't implement this method, then default implementation will be taken care automatically which is `super.onBackPressed()`

You override this method if you want to handle back functionality on your own, like showing a dialog to the user asking them are they really sure they want to exit the app, like that.

Example :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // do your work here
  super.onBackPressed(); // If you don't call super then default back functionality will not trigger at all. You may use this in your dialog if you don't want to use it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default super.onBackPressed() method would be called and it simply finishes the current activity.